# How to filter list by nested element using JSONPath?

Tags: json, jsonpath

How can one filter a list of items by a deeply nested value using JSONPath?

#### Test Data

```
[{
    "identifiers": [
        {
            "extension": "foo"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "identifiers": [
        {
            "extension": "bar"
        },
        {
            "extension": "baz"
        }
    ]
}]
```

#### Expected Result

```
[{
    "identifiers": [
        {
            "extension": "foo"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I've tried the following, but none of them work. I used the [JSONPath Tester](http://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/) to validate my results.

```
$[?(@.identifiers.[*].extension == 'foo')]
$[?(@.identifiers.*.extension == 'foo')]
$[?(@.identifiers[0].extension == 'foo')]
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
$..identifiers.[?(@.extension == "foo")]
```

works at http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ when you use Goessner.

at http://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/ I keep getting errors.

Comment: Strange, when I try it using Goessner on the herokuapp, I get `[{"extension" : "foo"}]`. I guess `curiousconcept` is bugged out, I was using that originally, but couldn't get anything working on it.